# Can the isomorphism theorems be generalized to regular categories?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory

Congruences and images can be defined in regular categories. We can also require existence of kernels and maybe finite products. With this it seems like it should be possible to state the [isomorphism theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Universal_algebra). Has this been studied, and what is known about it?

Comment: Do you know abelian category？

Comment: @Nakayama Yes, not every regular category is abelian however. And even the category of groups isn't so it wouldn't be strictly a generalization to look only at those.

Comment: Yes, in a regular category the image is the domain modulo the kernel pair. Is there something else you want to know?

Comment: Theorem A is more or less part of the definition of regular category (morphisms have images), so yes it's still valid.
Theorem B spells out in concrete terms what is the image of some subalgebra under a surjective map. I wouldn't say there is a meaningful generalization.
Theorem C does generalize: Given two effective congruences $Ψ$ and $Φ$ on $A$, if $Ψ ⊆ Φ$ then the kernel of $A/Ψ → A/Φ$ is the direct image of $Φ$ by the map $A^2→(A/ψ)^2$.

Comment: In Theorem D, the only part that doesn't is that the congruences do not form a complete lattice, only an inf-semilattice. I don't think the *effective* congruences even form an inf-semilattice. But if $A↠A/ψ$ is a regular epi, the poset of congruences of $A/ψ$ is isomorphic to the sub-poset of the congruences of $A$ containing $ψ$. Same for effective congruences.